# How to add parameters to a class decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript1.8

I want to create a decorator function for a class that can take a parameter.

Example

```
@Plugin("My first Plugin")
class myFirstPlugin {
   ...
}
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
function Plugin(constructor: Function, name:string){
    console.log("Plugin found: " + name);
}
```

I get an error in WebStorm saying:

> TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

How do I need to write this decorator function?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want your decorator to receive parameters then your decorator function needs to return the actual decorator function:

```
function PluginDecorator(name: string) {
    return (ctor: Function) => {
        console.log("Plugin found: " + name);
    }
}

@PluginDecorator("My first Plugin")
class myFirstPlugin {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20PluginDecorator(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(ctor%3A%20Function)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Plugin%20found%3A%20%22%20%2B%20name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40PluginDecorator(%22My%20first%20Plugin%22)%0D%0Aclass%20myFirstPlugin%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D))

I changed the name to `PluginDecorator` because `Plugin` already exists and the compiler complains about that name.

Comment: @Mohsen do not edit answer's in order to reply. And yes, the constructor is being called but only when you're doing `new myFirstPlugin()`

Comment: `ctor` is `undefined` in this example - shouldn't it point to `myFirstPlugin1?

Comment: @James `ctor` is not `undefined`, it is `myFirstPlugin`. (just change to: `console.log("Plugin found: " + name, ctor);`)

Comment: this is not a very substantive answer though.. You can't actually do anything with your class with this implementation. What is the form that modifies a class similar to `function decorator<T extends { new( ...args: any[]): {} }>(cTor: T) { return class extends cTor ...`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to access both the parameters and the constructor:

```js
type BaseClass = HTMLElement;

type Constructor = { new (...args: any[]): BaseClass };

export function Plugin(name: string) {
    return function <T extends Constructor>(constructor: T) {
        const cls = class extends constructor {
            // custom implementation here
        };

        // perhaps something like this
        customElements.define(name, cls, { extends: "div" });

        return cls;
    };
}
```